# Oracle AQ. Is it possible to change delay for message that already in a queue?

Tags: oracle, oracle-aq

My question desribed in a title, message has WAIT state, and I want to change delay date. If it isn't possible is there a way to dequeue message with WAIT state? Maybe I can dequeue some messages and enqueue with delay I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If my understanding is correct you are looking for the control over dequeue order. You can use dequeue_options parameter:

```
SQL> CREATE TYPE demo_queue_payload_type AS OBJECT
  2  ( message VARCHAR2(4000) );
  3  /

SQL> BEGIN
  2       DBMS_AQADM.CREATE_QUEUE_TABLE (
  3         queue_table        => 'demo_queue_table',
  4         queue_payload_type => 'demo_queue_payload_type'
  5         );
  6  END;
  7  /

SQL> BEGIN
  2  
  3      DBMS_AQADM.CREATE_QUEUE (
  4         queue_name  => 'demo_queue',
  5         queue_table => 'demo_queue_table'
  6         );
  7  
  8      DBMS_AQADM.START_QUEUE (
  9          queue_name => 'demo_queue'
 10      );
 11  
 12  END;
 13  /

SQL> CREATE TABLE message_track(msg varchar2(10), hndl raw(16))
  2  /

SQL> DECLARE
  2         r_enqueue_options    DBMS_AQ.ENQUEUE_OPTIONS_T;
  3         r_message_properties DBMS_AQ.MESSAGE_PROPERTIES_T;
  4         v_message_handle     RAW(16);
  5         o_payload            demo_queue_payload_type;
  6  
  7  BEGIN
  8  
  9        for i in 1..5 loop
 10  
 11            o_payload := demo_queue_payload_type('message '||i);
 12  
 13            DBMS_AQ.ENQUEUE(
 14                      queue_name         => 'demo_queue',
 15                      enqueue_options    => r_enqueue_options,
 16                      message_properties => r_message_properties,
 17                      payload            => o_payload,
 18                      msgid              => v_message_handle
 19            );
 20  
 21        insert into message_track values ('message '||i, v_message_handle);
 22  
 23        end loop;
 24  
 25       COMMIT;
 26  
 27  END;
 28  /

SQL> select * from  message_track
  2  /

MSG        HNDL                                                                 
---------- --------------------------------                                     
message 1  F25F320406C504B1E043441318AC5E0A                                     
message 2  F25F320406C604B1E043441318AC5E0A                                     
message 3  F25F320406C704B1E043441318AC5E0A                                     
message 4  F25F320406C804B1E043441318AC5E0A                                     
message 5  F25F320406C904B1E043441318AC5E0A                                     

SQL> select MSG_ID, user_data FROM   aq$demo_queue_table
  2  /

MSG_ID                                                                          
--------------------------------                                                
USER_DATA(MESSAGE)                                                              
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
F25F320406C504B1E043441318AC5E0A                                                
DEMO_QUEUE_PAYLOAD_TYPE('message 1')                                            

F25F320406C604B1E043441318AC5E0A                                                
DEMO_QUEUE_PAYLOAD_TYPE('message 2')                                            

F25F320406C704B1E043441318AC5E0A                                                
DEMO_QUEUE_PAYLOAD_TYPE('message 3')                                            


MSG_ID                                                                          
--------------------------------                                                
USER_DATA(MESSAGE)                                                              
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
F25F320406C804B1E043441318AC5E0A                                                
DEMO_QUEUE_PAYLOAD_TYPE('message 4')                                            

F25F320406C904B1E043441318AC5E0A                                                
DEMO_QUEUE_PAYLOAD_TYPE('message 5')                                            


SQL> set serveroutput on
SQL> DECLARE
  2         r_dequeue_options    DBMS_AQ.DEQUEUE_OPTIONS_T;
  3         r_message_properties DBMS_AQ.MESSAGE_PROPERTIES_T;
  4         v_message_handle     RAW(16);
  5         o_payload            demo_queue_payload_type;
  6  
  7  BEGIN
  8  
  9       DBMS_AQ.DEQUEUE(
 10          queue_name         => 'demo_queue',
 11          dequeue_options    => r_dequeue_options,
 12          message_properties => r_message_properties,
 13          payload            => o_payload,
 14          msgid              => v_message_handle
 15          );
 16  
 17       DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(
 18          '*** Dequeued message is [' || o_payload.message || '] ***'
 19          );
 20  
 21      COMMIT;
 22  
 23  END;
 24  /
*** Dequeued message is [message 1] ***                                         

SQL> DECLARE
  2         r_dequeue_options    DBMS_AQ.DEQUEUE_OPTIONS_T;
  3         r_message_properties DBMS_AQ.MESSAGE_PROPERTIES_T;
  4         v_message_handle     RAW(16);
  5         o_payload            demo_queue_payload_type;
  6  
  7  BEGIN
  8  
  9       for cur in (select * from message_track where msg = 'message 5') loop
 10         r_dequeue_options.msgid := cur.hndl;
 11       end loop;
 12  
 13  
 14       DBMS_AQ.DEQUEUE(
 15          queue_name         => 'demo_queue',
 16          dequeue_options    => r_dequeue_options,
 17          message_properties => r_message_properties,
 18          payload            => o_payload,
 19          msgid              => v_message_handle
 20          );
 21  
 22       DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(
 23          '*** Dequeued message is [' || o_payload.message || '] ***'
 24          );
 25  
 26      COMMIT;
 27  
 28  END;
 29  /
*** Dequeued message is [message 5] ***
```